What is the different between function and let?
I'm new to JS, I'm having problem to see what's the different between using let function and function. They do the same thing and I don't know which one has better use case or more efficient. Please do share your knowledge here.
The let function code :
let textInput = document.getElementId("textInput");
let myFunction = () => {
    if(textInput.value === ""){ 
        console.log("Failed"); 
    }
    else{
        console.log("Success"); 
    }
}

The function code :
let textInput = document.getElementId("textInput");
function myFunction() {
    if(textInput.value === ""){ 
        console.log("Failed"); 
    }
    else{
        console.log("Success"); 
    }
}

I googled it but most of them have paywall to know more, so this is the only free option I have. Thanks in advance.

I think the right question is what is the difference between arrow function and function expression

You can also do let myFunction = function() { depending on whether you want to confuse the question with the distinction between function() and () => (arrow function)
